# report a list to async method

Tags: c#, async-await, observablecollection

how can i report the progress of my query as a list to the main thread

```
 async private void getProductData()
    {
        Progress<List<string>> progress = new Progress<List<string>>(
                data => _prc.Add(new ProductList() {
                    Name  = data[1],
                    Delay = data[2],
                    Taxe  = data[3],
                }));
        await Task.Run(() => getTableDataFromDb(progress, "FOE_Diesel_High_CB"));

    }
  private void getTableDataFromDb(IProgress<List<string>> progress, string tabelName)
    {
          //Query logic her and report back the progress
           while (reader.Read())
           {
              progress.Report(??);
           }
    }
```

when i try to report a list of strings List<\string>  or a string array string[], the data displayed on my grid has always the same values and my app becomes very slow.
but when i try to report a single string it works fine.
Thanks

Comment: You don't use the variable `data` inside the the `_prc.Add(` code.

Comment: What is a ProductList?  You need to pass one to `Report` instead of creating one in the callback that it will be passed to.

Comment: `data` should be a list, but i dont know how to construct and return it from the Task

Comment: @ArhHokagi `data` is a `ProductList`.  I don't know what a `ProductList` is or how you need to create it, but you need to create it and pass it to the Report and just add it in your call back lambda you pass to the `Procress` constructor.

Comment: @juharr         I updated my question, it basicaly a  `List<string>` or  `string[]  `

Comment: `getTableDataFromDb` is reading from `reader` - but where is `reader` defined? If an async method (or any method) is reading from a reader that it didn't create or wasn't explicitly passed to it then that's a problem. Not just because it might not work, but also because it's very confusing.

Comment: @ArhHokagi Passing back a `ProductList` instead of a static sized list of `string` makes more sense to me.

Comment: @juharr        I can't because ProductList is an  observable collection that is data-bound to a UI element

Comment: Can you show the code for `ProductList`, because it doesn't look like a collection since you're only assigning values to 3 properties on it.

Comment: 'ProductList' is a class that have dependency properties (Name,Delay...) bound to my datagrid